# How to add item from ListView to string?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Im trying to get all the items from a listview into a string like so:

```
foreach(ListViewItem item in ListView1.Items)
{
     thisstring += item...?
}
```

item.Text is not a property of item...can seem to figure this out.  Any suggestions?

Comment: What is your aspx ? is there some control in the listview, may be a label, for which you want text ?

Answer (score 3):

You could use LINQ to select all items' `Text`.

```
var allItems = ListView1.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Select(i => i.Text);
var allItemText = String.Join(",", allItems);
```

Note that you need to add the `System.LINQ` namespace.

**Edit**: I've read `ListBox`, a ListView does not have a Text property and i'm not sure what text you actually want to concat.

Answer (score 1):

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach(ListViewItem item in ListView1.Items)
{
     sb.Append(item.Text);
     sb.Append(',');
}

Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString().TrimEnd(','));
```

EDIT: As Tim and Guest said, there is not Text property for ListViewItem in ASP.Net, [Windows Forms has ListViewItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.text.aspx) and it has the text property. [ASP.Net ListView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listviewitem.aspx) does not have Text property

Comment: +1 for using [StringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx).

Comment: @Guest, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.text.aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach(ListViewItem item in ListView1.Items)
{
     thisstring += item.Text+",";
}
    thisstring.TrimEnd(',');
```

isn't it that simple.

Answer (score 0):

```
   string.Join(" ", ListView1.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Select(i => i.Text).ToArray());
```